# swagger-codegen-maven-plugin generate interface implementation even if option interfaceOnly = true is used

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I want to generate JAX-RS server stubs for my API using the swagger-codegen-maven plugin 3.0.16 , but I want to use my own service implementation class, instead of the one generated. 
In my config , I have specify config option interfaceOnly = true but 
it does not work

My current maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.16</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
          <language>jaxrs-resteasy-eap</language>
          <output>${project.basedir}</output>
          <configOptions>
            <sourceFolder>src/main/java</sourceFolder>
            <apiPackage>be.xxx.zzzz.api</apiPackage>
            <modelPackage>be.xxx.zzzz.representations</modelPackage>
            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
            <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
            <java8>false</java8>
            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
            <returnResponse>true</returnResponse>
            <generateAdditionalProperties>true</generateAdditionalProperties>
            <customPatchAnnotation>be.xxx.rest.commons.annotations.PATCH</customPatchAnnotation>
          </configOptions>
          <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```